# Codelyzer doesn't report errors in HTML/CSS files

Tags: angular, angular-cli, codelyzer

I just created a fresh project using @angular/cli (latest version - 1.1.3) and I'm facing some issues with codelyzer.

Let's see the code what I have right now:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  private title = 'app'; // Should warn here
}
```

**app.component.css:**

```
spam { // Intentionally wrong to warn errors
  color: red;
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{title}}!!</h1>
```

**tslint.json:** (only codelyzer part):

```
"use-input-property-decorator": true,
"use-output-property-decorator": true,
"use-host-property-decorator": true,
"no-input-rename": true,
"no-output-rename": true,
"use-life-cycle-interface": true,
"use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
"component-class-suffix": true,
"directive-class-suffix": true,
"no-access-missing-member": true,
"templates-use-public": true,
"invoke-injectable": true,
"no-unused-css": true
```

---

After ran `ng lint`:

Actual behavior:

> All files pass linting.

Expected behavior:

Warns the rule "templates-use-public":

- There's a private variable that is used in HTML;

Warns the rule "no-unused-css":

- The CSS isn't being used;

Note that these examples are just a few of the ones I've tried. In fact, it seems like *codelyzer* isn't watching or reporting any errors in **.css** or **.html** files.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem - in particular, `template-use-public` is blatantly ignored.

Comment: Same problem here with "Angular CLI: 6.0.8", I can't get `ng lint` to output any problems for my html files.